# LUIS fails on exporting a model

Tags: azure-language-understanding

We've been happily importing/exporting LUIS models with no problems. Unfortunately our main model has suddenly stopped exporting. When I try and "Export App", my browser just displays ...

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Failure",
    "message": "One or more errors occurred. Corresponding activity ID: f4ac0b21-1453-438b-a5cd-6543bdc7d868."
  }
}
```

I've tried a new session, different browser, the issue has persisted for a few days. I suspect it's a bug with LUIS itself perhaps, but does Anybody have any suggestions for resolving this?

Comment: Have you tried the API, perhaps via the test console?https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40

Comment: Thanks, but after a few days of failing, it started working again today. Seems MS may have fixed something (nothing else changed on our side).

Answer (score 0):

This resolved itself after a few days, with no changes on our side. This suggests perhaps something was fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: Were you allways using the same browser? We sometimes face issues with Azure and/or LUIS web when using IE11 and the same operation from the same client profile can be performed without problem in other browser.

Comment: I tried multiple browsers at the time and had been exporting previously. All works now.